# Why does Chandra ride a chariot pulled by antelope?

Tags: navagraha, chandra, soma, iconography

I am just trying to understand the broader symbolism of Chandra Dev and they say he is often depicted being pulled in a chariot with three wheels with up to 3 or more white horses or sometimes by antelope. I was wondering does Antelope have any significance in Hindu cosmology and how does this relate to Chandra Dev?

Comment: Rabbit and antelopes are both ruled by Monn (or associated with Moon) .. Moon represents the mind .. just like the mind both these animals are extremely fast moving and are always changing positions.